# SUPERHOT MCD saves seemingly wiped

Tags: steam, technical-issues, superhot-mind-control-delete

I got a new computer, loaded Steam onto it, and tried launching SUPERHOT MCD on it to see if it handled it well. Unfortunately, it ended up starting a new game instead of loading my existing save.

When I went back to my main computer and started MCD, it loaded the "new save" that my new computer had just created!

I tried toggling the "sync to cloud" option in the library and restarting Steam. Nothing. I also tried finding the save file in `AppData`. I managed to find a `.mcd` file that was created around the time that I launched on my old computer after launching it on my new computer.

When I check [here](https://store.steampowered.com/account/remotestorage), for MCD, it shows 1 file, and under "Date Written", it says "11 Nov @ 7:51am" (so that's the new save, not the old one).

I find this odd because previously for other games, Steam has warned me that newer game files are available, and asks me which version I want to load. This time it didn't ask though.

Is there any way to get my previous save files back?

Comment: Although an old post there's something [here about save locations](https://steamcommunity.com/app/322500/discussions/0/412448158167284423/) but it's 2 years out of date so might not apply anymore. Looks like [devs had to help one person out](https://steamcommunity.com/app/322500/discussions/1/312265327166876597/)

Comment: @Smock I've checked the locallow, and it only contains the new one. I ended up just starting over.